# Storing unstructured json data in postgres json field or S3?

Tags: json, postgresql, amazon-s3

I am working on an application which allows users to create and save small "programs" which are composed of JSON arrays of "instructions."

The instructions can come with a lot of metadata, and the entire program can be rather large (up to 6mb). The end program is to be consumed and executed inside of a lambda function.

#### The question I have is: **What is the best way to persist these json programs**?

The options I was considering are:

1. Postgres json field (I'm already using postgres on the REST API)
2. S3 key value store

I was wondering if there were performance bottlenecks with Postgesql JSON field on larger objects, and what some of the trade offs were between the two stores. If you have experience working with either, I'd love to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Do you need to search inside the JSON values using SQL?

Comment: No, just need to read the whole file at once and pass to lambda

Comment: What did you ultimately decide to go with? @ZacharyDenham

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was marked as solved by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46411848/8691571) and IMO it solves this one as well.

;tldr
If you really just need to read the `json` by id and you won't be needing any of the SQL features go with S3. It stores objects as key-value pairs and is cheaper.